# Enclosing contour lines along edges

Tags: qgis, line, contour, polyline-creation

I have contour lines that I am converting to polygons. Contours along the edge are clipped so are difficult to simply convert to polygons. So I'm trying to find an automated way to do this within QGIS.

Unfortunately, these contour lines don't have an elevation attribute to use and are simply indicative

Here is an example of what I mean:
[image]

I have thought a way could be to extract the start/end vertices. Then somehow give them an ordered clockwise `"ID"`, then iterate "Points to Path" leaving a gap between each line. I tried using `@row_number` but the `"ID"`'s aren't exactly clockwise.

Comment: No, I don't unfortunately so I have to work what I have.

Comment: There are several ideas: [1] Join multiple lines Plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/joinmultiplelines/ [2] Apply the ["Minimum bounding geometry"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#minimum-bounding-geometry) (Convex Hull) > then the ["Polygons to lines"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#polygons-to-lines) (Maybe with the ["Multipart to singleparts"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#multipart-to-singleparts) on the first step)

Comment: Try something and ask a more specific question. We cant know if you have some attribute which can be used, if they are multlines etc.. Or share the data

Answer (score 3):

Add a [*Virtual Layer*](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers)

- `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

and run

```sql
SELECT c.<column1>,
       c.<column2>, 
       ...,
       ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(geometry, ST_StartPoint(geometry)) AS geometry
FROM   <contour_layer_name>
WHERE NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(geometry), ST_EndPoint(geometry))
UNION ALL
SELECT c.<column1>,
       c.<column2>, 
       ...,
       ST_MakePolygon(geometry) AS geometry
FROM   <contour_layer_name>
WHERE ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(geometry), ST_EndPoint(geometry))
;
```

This will close each 'open' contour by connecting its end to start point, and then generate polygons. Closing lines will not follow the 'square' at its corners, and might create invalid geometries there.

Comment: Added a filter for open, and a `UNION' with already closed contours. If the corner cases are an issue, it is possible to include the corner point, too. Add a comment then and I'll update the answer.

Comment: I don't have much experience with SQL and virtual layers. I tried copying this into the Query and replacing  <contour_layer_name> with the name of my layer but I am getting a syntax error. I think there is a missing bracket on 4th line, I tried fixing that but am still getting a syntax error:

Comment: Here is the error: Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS SELECT c.<column1>,
       c.<column2>, 
       ...,
       ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(geometry, ST_StartPoint(geometry)) AS geometry
FROM   Contours
WHERE NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(geometry), ST_EndPoint(geometry)))
UNION ALL
SELECT c.<column1>,
       c.<column2>, 
       ...,
       ST_MakePolygon(geometry) AS geometry
FROM   Contours
WHERE ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(geometry), ST_EndPoint(geometry))
;: 1 - near "<": syntax error

Comment: @JGIS you need to replace the `<column1>` placeholders with the actual names of the fields you want to include. It has to be the same list in both sides of the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: e.g. `c.<column1>` may be `c."id"`

Comment: are these existing fields or just naming the fields being created?